# Find all html content between heading tags and wrap it with section tag in Python

Tags: python-3.x

In Pythong, I want to wrap content section with section tags. I have the following html content:

```
<h2>Heading 2.1</h2>
<p>Para 1</p>
<p>Para 2</p>
<h3>Heading 3.1</h3>
<p>Para 3</p>
<p>Para 4</p>
<h2>Heading 2.2</h2>
<p>Para 5</p>
<h3>Heading 3.2</h3>
<p>Para 6</p>
```

And I want it to become

```
<section id="1">
    <h2>Heading 2.1</h2>
    <p>Para 1</p>
    <p>Para 2</p>
    <section id="1.1">
        <h3>Heading 3.1</h3>
        <p>Para 3</p>
        <p>Para 4</p>
    </section>
</section>
<section id="2">
    <h2>Heading 2.2</h2>
    <p>Para 5</p>
    <section id="2.1">
        <h3>Heading 3.2</h3>
        <p>Para 6</p>
    </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd give this a go but it ended up being more difficult than I hoped and I couldn't figure out ways of doing it without some inadvisable behaviour such as modifying a string (or rather replacing it, since strings are immutable) while I'm iterating through it.

I'm sure there's a much better way and hope someone else suggests it, but here's what I did:

```
html_string = '''<h2>Heading 2.1</h2>
<p>Para 1</p>
<p>Para 2</p>
<h3>Heading 3.1</h3>
<p>Para 3</p>
<p>Para 4</p>
<h2>Heading 2.2</h2>
<p>Para 5</p>
<h3>Heading 3.2</h3>
<p>Para 6</p>'''

def depth_wrap(input_string, current_depth, base_heading_label = ""):

    # Index to track where we're searching from in the string.
    current_search_index = 0
    # Counter for number of sections seen at this depth.
    depth_counter = 1

    # String we'll insert on ending a section.
    end_section_string = '\n</section>\n'

    # Set the return string to the input string.
    return_string = input_string

    # Loop through looking for Headings
    while True:

        # String we'll insert if we find a new heading.
        start_string_to_insert = '<section id="' + base_heading_label + str(depth_counter) + '">\n'
        #  String to search for headings at the current depth.
        search_string = '<h' + str(current_depth) + '>'

        # Where is the next header at this depth?
        index_of_next_header = return_string.find(search_string, current_search_index)

        # Where is the next header at this depth, after the above one.
        index_of_next_header_at_same_depth = return_string.find(search_string, index_of_next_header +1)

        # If no headers found, then break the loop.
        if index_of_next_header == -1:
            break

        # Is this the last header at this depth?
        if index_of_next_header_at_same_depth == -1:
            # Extract content from this header to the end of the string.
            string_between_headers = return_string[index_of_next_header:]

            # Look for any headers at the next level down, recurse, and then end the section.
            next_level_string = depth_wrap(string_between_headers, current_depth + 1, base_heading_label + str(depth_counter) + '.')\
                                + end_section_string
            # Replace the string between with the updated result from above.
            return_string = return_string.replace(string_between_headers, next_level_string, 1)

            # Add the start of the section last to avoid shifting the indices.
            return_string = return_string[:index_of_next_header] + start_string_to_insert + return_string[index_of_next_header:]
            break
        else:
            # Extract content from between this header and the next.
            string_between_headers = return_string[index_of_next_header: index_of_next_header_at_same_depth]

            # Look for any headers at the next level down, recurse, and then end the section.
            next_level_string = depth_wrap(string_between_headers, current_depth + 1, base_heading_label + str(depth_counter) + '.') \
                                + end_section_string
            # Replace the string between with the updated result from above.
            return_string = return_string.replace(string_between_headers, next_level_string, 1)
            # Add the start of the section last to avoid shifting the indices.
            return_string = return_string[:index_of_next_header] + start_string_to_insert + return_string[index_of_next_header:]

            # Update the search index to search from after the updated section of text.
            current_search_index = index_of_next_header + len(start_string_to_insert) + len(next_level_string)

            # Update the depth counter for labelling.
            depth_counter += 1

    # Strip any extra line returns or spaces from end and return.
    return return_string.strip()


print(depth_wrap(html_string, 2))
```

I also couldn't get the indentation to work consistently for all cases, so have left that out. A module like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) can prettify the output if you need it.